# External Vault Authentication Permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, hashicorp-vault

I am a beginner in vault and I am trying to set up an external vault for the Kubernetes application using https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-external-vault It is working completely fine if everything is on a local machine same as a tutorial but In my case, I have setup vault HA on AWS EC2 and I have a separate Kubernetes cluster in which I have set up sidecar container using Helm chart as mentioned in the tutorial. I already set up Kubernetes configuration, roles, and policy on vault server but when my application starts with annotation to get secret from vault I am getting error permisson denied from vault init container.

Does anyone please help with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: check the service account, vault policy and the vault. without these details its hard to tell why the auth not working

Comment: https://github.com/Adiii717/vault-sidecar-injector-app/blob/main/README.md#start-minikube-in-ec2 here is the repo that might help you

Comment: it invole vault and Kubernetes should be able to talk each other, Kubernetes auth should be enable, the service account that is attached with vault policy should be use by the pod, the path assign with service account should be correct, I am trying best to help ;)

Comment: @Adiii Thank you so much for your help. kubernetes auth is already enabled and In that I am using same SA which I attached to the pod.Also I have already setup roles and policy

Comment: Then can you please share minimal reproduce able manifest

Comment: I am using same configuration e.g pod files, policy,roles as this tutorial https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-external-vault but only difference is that my vault server is setup on EC2 so while installing helm chart instead of external-vault service I am passing public IP of EC2 instance and also I have create a vault namespace in which I am installing helm chart, pod etc

Comment: did you check this out https://github.com/Adiii717/vault-sidecar-injector-app/blob/main/README.md#start-minikube-in-ec2? any help here

Comment: both are reachable? i mean is Kubernetes able to reach to vault and vault to Kubernetes ? whats the error logs in the vault init container? can you share the full error?

Comment: As already mentioned, sharing your manifest code to be able to reproduce would be really beneficial.

Comment: @Adiii here is the error I am getting 2022-08-24T15:45:35.993Z [INFO]  auth.handler: authenticating
2022-08-24T15:45:36.007Z [ERROR] auth.handler: error authenticating:
  error=
  | Error making API request.
  | 
  | URL: PUT http://PUBLIC-IP-EC2:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
  | Code: 403. Errors:
  | 
  | * permission denied

Comment: It's policy issue

Comment: my policy looks like this : path "secret/app/dev" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}

Comment: No, it should be kv/..., which secret engine you are using?

Comment: I am using kv secret engine

Comment: Then why secret policy? It should be kv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247523/discussion-between-adiii-and-donal).

Comment: @Adiii and Donal Did you find a solution for the issue? Because I would benefit from it a lot.

Comment: @tobias whats the error in your case?